# Is A a subset or an element of set C?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let A, B, C be 3 sets. If A belongs to B, and B is a subset of C, is it true that A is a subset of C?

They say A is a set. So A should be a subset of C. 
But my textbook says it’s not because A is an element (as seen in the belongs to area).

So what is the question trying to say? I’m really confused.

Comment: if $A$ is an element of $B$ and $B$ is a subset of $C$ then $A$ is an element of $C$, whether or not $A$ is a set

Comment: But is A a subset of C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** In general, an object can be *both* a set on its own, and an element of another set.

In your particular case, as [J. W. Tanner](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/615567/j-w-tanner)'s question [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3599693/is-a-a-subset-or-and-element-of-set-c#comment7399574_3599693) indicates, $A$ is an element of $C$ (due to it being an element of $B$ and $B$ being a subset of $C$) regardless of its status of whether or not it is a set on its own.

For $A$ to be a subset of $C$, it must either be empty or contain *at least* one element of $C$. However, the only specific element of $C$ you are given is $A$ itself, but $A$ doesn't contain itself as an element of its own set.

Answer (score 2):

The question tests if you've understood the difference between membership of a set and subsets. A quick example to help settle this.

Let $A=\{1,2\},B=\{3,4\}$ and $C=\{\{1,2\},3,4\}$.

The three objects $\{1,2\}$, $3$ and $4$ are elements of $C$. So, the object $A$ (which is a *set on its own*) is an element of $C$.

Given two sets $S$, $T$:

$T$ is subset of $S$, if and only if $x \in T \implies x \in S \hspace{3mm} \forall x$.

Thus, $B=\{3,4\}$ is a subset of $C$.

Further, the singleton set that contains the object $A$:

$T = \{A\} =\{\{1,2\}\}$ is a subset of $C$.

Answer (score 0):

- In general, an element of a subset of a set S is not a subset of S.

That is, from " it is an element of a subset of S " you ***cannot*** infer automatically that it is also a subset of S. The reason is not a sufficient one.

- But note also, that it is ***not either a sufficient reason to conclude that it is not a subset*** of S.

It ***can happen*** that an element of a subset of S is also a subset of S.

- Example :

Since $2=_{df}\{0,1\}$, it is true that $1\in 2$.

Since $3 =_{df} \{0,1,2\}$,   it is true that $2\subseteq 3$ ( that is : 2 is a subset of 3).

Since $1=_{df}\{0\}$ , $1\subseteq 3$.

So, number $1$ is an element of a subset of number$3$ ***and*** is also a subset of $3$.

Note : logically speaking , the key point is to understand this : the fact that " A implies B" is not a true general rule does not mean that "A implies not-B" is a true general rule.